# Search and use of Strings in 2D Arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I got a 2D array where I want to fetch data from the 2nd dimension based on the 1st, but I dont understand how to set it up in Swift 2 since the old for-loop function is deprecated.

Based on the name (Burt) I want to present the phone-No and Group.

```
myArray: [[String]] = [["Adam", "123456", "Group1"], ["Burt", "251436", "Group2"], ["Cesar", "918273", "Group3"], ["David", "552277", "Group4"]

For i in 0..myArray.count {
   If myArray[i][0] == "Burt" {
      phoneNoLabel.text = myArray[i][1]
      GroupNoLabel.text = myArray[i][2]
   }
}
```

This is how I solved it with the help of Tarun Seera.

```
let myArray = [["Adam", "123456", "Group1"], ["Burt", "251436", "Group2"], ["Cesar", "918273", "Group3"], ["David", "552277", "Group4"]]

var user: String = "Burt"
var phoneNo: String = ""
var groupNo: String = ""

for i in myArray {
    if i[0] == user {
        phoneNo = i[1]
        groupNo = i[2]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also keep details in form of entity in array and use predicate too, for 2d array solution see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also make entities (NSObject)array and use predicate to achieve the same thing and still if you want this form 2d array you can use below code

```
let myArray = [["Adam", "123456", "Group1"], ["Burt", "251436", "Group2"], ["Cesar", "918273", "Group3"], ["David", "552277", "Group4"]]

    for i in myArray {
    if i[0] == "Burt" {
        print("Hurrey I am in.. my name is: \(i[0]) my Id is:\(i[1]) and my gourp is:\(i[2])")
    }
    }
```

Comment: This seems to have solved my issue with the initial question and after modifying it I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
   for i in 0..<myArray.count {
      if myArray[i][0] == "Burt" {
         phoneNoLabel.text = myArray[i][1]
         GroupNoLabel.text = myArray[i][2]
      }
   }
```

Use

> ..<

instead of just

> ..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that i is going from 0 to myArray.count - which is 4 .. that means your i is going 0,1,2,3,4 = you have 5 times i. Your array only has 4 "items".

```
for i in 1...myArray.count{
    if myArray[i-1][0] == "Burt" {
        phoneNoLabel.text = myArray[i-1][1]
        GroupNoLabel.text = myArray[i-1][2]
    }
}
```

or

```
for i in 0...myArray.count-1{
    if myArray[i][0] == "Burt" {
        phoneNoLabel.text = myArray[i][1]
        GroupNoLabel.text = myArray[i][2]
    }
}
```

should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to explicit looping, you could use a functional programming approach

```
let searchForUser = "Burt"
let userInfo = Array(myArray
    .flatMap{ $0.first == searchForUser ? $0.suffixFrom(1) : nil }
    .flatten())

print(userInfo) // ["251436", "Group2"]
```

---

For you specific example, the user info you're after is readily obtainable from the `userInfo` array

```
phoneNoLabel.text = userInfo[0] // 251436
groupNoLabel.text = userInfo[1] // Group2
```

Note here that I've renamed `GroupNoLabel` variable (`UILabel`?) from the example in your question to `groupNoLabel`, as *variables* in Swift should, by convention, use `camelCase` names (and not `CamelCase`, as is used e.g. for *types*).